# How to show that a Banach space is a subspace of another Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

I'm having some trouble showing that the following Banach space is a subspace of $\ell^1(\mathbb{N} )$

$\ell^1_w(\mathbb{N} ) = \{ \{x_k\}^\infty_{k=1}| x_k \in \mathbb{C}, \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k|\cdot2^k < \infty \}$

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us what $w_k$ is?

Comment: You certainly have a list of properties you need to check, don't you? Can you be more specific then about which property is the most difficult for you to check? Assuming it is the property that $f+g\in \ell^1_w$ for $f,g\in \ell^1_w$, you may try use the triangle inequality for $\ell^1$ without weights, in a clever way.

Comment: Sorry menag, I forgot to mention that $w_k = 2^k$.

Comment: Thanks Bananach, I will try that.

Comment: Is there another way to answer this question without the triangle inequality?

Comment: This is not a subspace of $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{N})$. Consider $x_k = 1, k \in \mathbb{N}$, this is in $\ell_{\omega}^{1}(\mathbb{N}$ but not in $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{N})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in \ell^1_w$. Then we have, as $1 \le 2^k$ for every $k$ that 
$$ \sum_k |x_k| \le \sum_k 2^k |x_k| < \infty $$
that is $x \in \ell^1$. Therefore $\ell^1_w \subseteq \ell^1$, it remains to show that it is a subspace, that is $x+\lambda y \in \ell^1_w$ for every $x,y \in \ell^1_w$, $\lambda \in \mathbf K$.